# Reindex certain level of multiindex dataframe

Tags: pandas

It seems like multiindex dataframe doesn't support reindex method for certain level.
Here is sample code.

```
id = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [
    ["AAPL","GOOGL"],pd.bdate_range("2022-01-01","2022-06-30")
    ]
)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(np.size(id)),index=id,columns=["integer"])
display(df)
```

```
                  integer
AAPL  2022-01-03        0
      2022-01-04        1
      2022-01-05        2
      2022-01-06        3
      2022-01-07        4
...                   ...
GOOGL 2022-06-24      253
      2022-06-27      254
      2022-06-28      255
      2022-06-29      256
      2022-06-30      257
```

In this example, level 1 consist of business(Weekday) dates.
If I try to do reindex with 7 days date range, the result is the same.

```
df = df.reindex(pd.date_range("2022-01-01","2022-06-30"),level=1,fill_value=0)
display(df)
```

```
#Index level 1 should include weekend such as 2022-01-01
                  integer
AAPL  2022-01-03        0
      2022-01-04        1
      2022-01-05        2
      2022-01-06        3
      2022-01-07        4
...                   ...
GOOGL 2022-06-24      253
      2022-06-27      254
      2022-06-28      255
      2022-06-29      256
      2022-06-30      257
```

When I try reindex with multiindex, it works as expected.

```
df = df.reindex(
    pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["AAPL","GOOGL"],pd.date_range("2022-01-01","2022-06-30")]),
    fill_value=0)
display(df)
```

```
                  integer
AAPL  2022-01-01        0
      2022-01-02        0
      2022-01-03        0
      2022-01-04        1
      2022-01-05        2
...                   ...
GOOGL 2022-06-26        0
      2022-06-27      254
      2022-06-28      255
      2022-06-29      256
      2022-06-30      257
```

My question is that should I just use multiindex if I want to do reindex?
In that case, what is for 'level' argument in reindex method?

Comment: pandas reindex on a level does not `blow` up - it just adjusts within the existing MultiIndex - if you pass a smaller size, with just values currently existing, it will shrink. with the multiindex argument however, you are building a new index altogether, allowing for the `blow up`

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. By the way, what would be the best practice for the sample case? Should I just build multiindex or is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Building a MultiIndex is fine, as you have more control